Trying to setup dhcp-dyndns with samba ad - RPC fails
I want to get dhcp-dyndns working on my samba server (running on ubuntu 24.04) but I am stuck on the following:
sudo samba-tool dns add server spatiebas.net hp-ubuntu A 192.168.2.163  --use-kerberos=required

resolve_lmhosts: Attempting lmhosts lookup for name server<0x20>
dcerpc: bind_nak reason 0 - NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
Failed to bind to uuid 50abc2a4-574d-40b3-9d66-ee4fd5fba076 for ncacn_ip_tcp:2a02:a476:8f3e:1:67c:16ff:fed8:6f1a[49153,sign,target_hostname=server,abstract_syntax=50abc2a4-574d-40b3-9d66-ee4fd5fba076/0x00000005,localaddress=2a02:a476:8f3e:1:67c:16ff:fed8:6f1a] NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
ERROR: Connecting to DNS RPC server server with binding ncacn_ip_tcp:server[sign] failed with (3221225473, '{Operation Failed} The requested operation was unsuccessful.')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/dns.py", line 52, in dns_connect
    dns_conn = dnsserver.dnsserver(binding_str, lp, creds)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


When I run the command without --use-kerberos I am allowed to add/delete dns entries. But the samba script dhcp-dyndns.sh is running in dhcpd users context, and requires to be executed with the --use-kerberos
I have little knowledge on kerberos/RPC/KDC and am completely stuck. Unfortunately google/chat gpt doesn't get me any further. Going in circles for a while now.
Anybody has some expertise on this? Also background info of which parts of software are interacting how is appreciated

What is the version of Ubuntu being used?

Hey, ubuntu 24.04
